# How to use Function's Arguments in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables, scope, arguments

I'm trying to understand the best way to use a function's arguments in nested functions:

Here are my thoughts:

These are a bunch of functions I first declare to use them later in other functions:

```
//Habitaciones restantes
        function rleft($from, $to, $room_type_id){
            //Acceso a DB
                require('/some-path/database.php');
            //url parameters
                require ('/some-path/getparam.php');
            //Hotel Room Data
                $customroom = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM hotel_room_type WHERE room_type_id = '$room_type_id'");
                $customroomtotal = mysqli_num_rows($customroom);
                $customroomData = mysqli_fetch_array($customroom);
                $roominventory = $customroomData['room_type_inventory'];
            //Obteniendo lista de disponibilidad
                $customavailable = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM booking_check_avilability WHERE room_type_id = '1' AND check_in_date = '$from' AND check_out_date = '$to'");
                $customavailabletotal = mysqli_num_rows($customavailable);
                mysqli_close($conn);
                if($customavailabletotal > 0) {
                    while($customavailableData = mysqli_fetch_array($customavailable))  {         
                            $inventariodisponible = $roominventory - $customavailableData['total_room'] -$customavailableData['blocked_inventory'];
                    }
                } mysqli_free_result($customavailable);
                mysqli_close(conn);
            return $inventariodisponible;
        }
    //Creamos el array donde se almacenarán todos los dias entre las 2 fechas del cliente
        function createRange($startDate, $endDate) {
                $tmpDate = new DateTime($startDate);
                $tmpEndDate = new DateTime($endDate);
                $outArray = array();
                do {
                    $outArray[] = $tmpDate->format('Y-m-d');
                } while ($tmpDate->modify('+1 day') < $tmpEndDate);
            return $outArray;
        }
    //creamos un array donde se almacenará la dispo para cada una de las fechas del cliente
        function inout($room_type_id){
         require ('/some-path/getparam.php');   
            $datearray = createRange("$fromdate", "$todate", "$room_type_id");
            $arraycount = count($datearray);
            $leftarray = array();
            foreach ($datearray as $value) {
                $from = $value;
                $to = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value . "+1 days"));
                $leftarray[] = rleft($from, $to);
            }
            return $leftarray;
        }
    //Room or Rooms?
        function sp(){
        require ('/some-path/getparam.php');
            if (rleft($fromdate, $todate, $room_type_id) == 1) {
                $rq = "room";
            }
            else{
                $rq = "rooms";
        }
        return $rq;
        }
    //Habitaciones restantes
        function availablerooms(){
            //Acceso a DB
            require('/some-path/database.php');
            //url parameters
            require ('/some-path/getparam.php');
          $keyarray = createrange($fromdate, $todate);
          $valuearray = inout();
          $joinarray = array();
          foreach ($keyarray as $i => $key) {
              $joinarray[$key] = $valuearray[$i];
          }
          return $joinarray;
        }
```

So here is the main function:

```
//Función para checkar si hay disponibilidad para las fechas seleccionadas
    function next($room_type_id){
        //basic include files
            require('/some-path/database.php');
        //url parameters
            require ('/some-path/getparam.php');
        //Checkamos que haya dispo
        $inoutarray = inout("$room_type_id");
        foreach ($inoutarray as $value) {
           if ($value < $rooms) {
               echo "Sorry NO rooms available!"; //no hay habitaciones disponibles
                    echo "</br>";
                        ?>
                        <!-- Escondemos el botón de submit de la habitación -->
                        <style type="text/css">.bromeliabtn{
                        display:none!important;
                        }</style>
                        <!-- Cambiamos el estilo del msj -->
                        <style type="text/css">.bromeliadsbl span{
                        color: #c58e21!important;
                        font-size: 20px!important;
                        line-height: 25px!important;
                        }</style>
                        <?php
                        $cond = true;//asignamos un valor a $cond
                            break; // si match entonces termina el loop
           }else{
            unset($cond);
            $cond = false;//si hay disponibilidad entonces sumar 1 a $cond
           }
        }
        //si las fechas tienen dispo entonces seguimos :)
        if ($cond == false) {//si $cond es 2 entonces podemos seguir
            allowed();
        }
        
    }
        //Esta función nos permite obtener los precios tanto de temporada como normales de acuerdo a la fecha especificada.
            function allowed($room_type_id){
            //Acceso a la base de datos
                require('/some-path/database.php');
                require ('/some-path/getparam.php');
                  //Creamos la consulta para precios por temporada
            $sql = "SELECT `seasonal_price`"
                . " FROM `hotel_seasonal_price`"
                . " WHERE `room_type_id` = '$room_type_id'"
                . " AND `room_person` =  '$Room1'"
                . " AND `seasonal_price_deleted` =  '0'"
                . " AND '" . $fromdate . "' = seasonal_from"
                //. " AND '" . $currentdate . "' = 'seasonal_to'"
                . " LIMIT 1";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
                $seasonalprice = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (!$seasonalprice) {
                    die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
                } else {
                    while ($standard2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($seasonalprice)) {
                        //echo "$ " . $standard2['seasonal_price']  . "";
                        $stdrd = $standard2['seasonal_price'];
                        echo "$ ";
                        echo number_format((float)($stdrd + ((10*$stdrd)/100)), 2, '.', ''); //sumamos el porcentaje de descuento que luego sera restado en el precio principal
                        echo " ";
                        ?>
                        <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: helvetica; color: #ff0000; font-size: 15px;"><span style="color: #333333;">(Seasonal price)</span></span></p>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            } 
            else {
            // Hacemos la consulta para obtener el precio sin importar fechas... solo como referencia
                $weekend = date('l', strtotime($datefrom));
                switch ($weekend) {
                    case "Friday":
                        $sql = "SELECT `room_price_fri` FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE room_type_id = '$room_type_id' AND `room_person` =  '$Room1' AND `price_deleted` = '0'";
                            $standardprice = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            if (!$standardprice) {
                                die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
                            //movemos el "while" dentro del "else"
                            } 
                            else {
                                while ($standard = mysqli_fetch_array($standardprice, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                    $stdrd2 = $standard['room_price_fri'];
                                    echo "$ ";
                                    echo number_format((float)$stdrd2, 2, '.', '');
                                    ?>
                                    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: helvetica; color: #ff4c00; font-size: 12px;"><span style="color: rgba(255, 76, 0, 0.63);"><?php echo "10% OFF"; ?></span></span></p>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                mysqli_close($conn); //cerramos la conexión con la base de datos
                            }
                        break;
                    case "Saturday":
                        $sql = "SELECT `room_price_sat` FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE room_type_id = '$room_type_id' AND `room_person` =  '$Room1' AND `price_deleted` = '0'";
                            $standardprice = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            if (!$standardprice) {
                                die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
                            //movemos el "while" dentro del "else"
                            } 
                            else {
                                while ($standard = mysqli_fetch_array($standardprice, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                    $stdrd2 = $standard['room_price_sat'];
                                    echo "$ ";
                                    echo number_format((float)$stdrd2, 2, '.', '');
                                    ?>
                                    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: helvetica; color: #ff4c00; font-size: 12px;"><span style="color: rgba(255, 76, 0, 0.63);"><?php echo "10% OFF"; ?></span></span></p>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                mysqli_close($conn); //cerramos la conexión con la base de datos
                            }
                        break;
                    case "Sunday":
                        $sql = "SELECT `room_price_sun` FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE room_type_id = '$room_type_id' AND `room_person` =  '$Room1' AND `price_deleted` = '0'";
                            $standardprice = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            if (!$standardprice) {
                                die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
                            //movemos el "while" dentro del "else"
                            } 
                            else {
                                while ($standard = mysqli_fetch_array($standardprice, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                    $stdrd2 = $standard['room_price_sun'];
                                    echo "$ ";
                                    echo number_format((float)$stdrd2, 2, '.', '');
                                    ?>
                                    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: helvetica; color: #ff4c00; font-size: 12px;"><span style="color: rgba(255, 76, 0, 0.63);"><?php echo "10% OFF"; ?></span></span></p>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                mysqli_close($conn); //cerramos la conexión con la base de datos
                            }
                        break;
                    default:
                        $sql = "SELECT `room_price` FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE room_type_id = '$room_type_id' AND `room_person` =  '$Room1' AND `price_deleted` = '0'";
                            $standardprice = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            if (!$standardprice) {
                                die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
                            //movemos el "while" dentro del "else"
                            } 
                            else {
                                while ($standard = mysqli_fetch_array($standardprice, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                    $stdrd2 = $standard['room_price'];
                                    echo "$ ";
                                    echo number_format((float)$stdrd2, 2, '.', '');
                                    ?>
                                    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: helvetica; color: #ff4c00; font-size: 12px;"><span style="color: rgba(255, 76, 0, 0.63);"><?php echo "10% OFF"; ?></span></span></p>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                mysqli_close($conn); //cerramos la conexión con la base de datos
                            }
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

So here is my doubt, the argument: `$room_type_id` is the only one which I need to change in the main function to get what I want from every room in the database, and each function should be used with that variable as parameter to change such information... my question is, if I define the room type id once in the main variable, will this be also accepted and used for all the others functions as a value for this argument? lets say:

```
function next("7");
```

Will the number 7 be used for all the other nested functions inside this function as a value for the same argument?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your code is likely vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound 
parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prep
ared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examp
les.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i'm still trying to learn, i'll read the documentation and examples and see if i understand it... thanks for pointing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the number 7 be used for all the other nested functions inside this function as a value for the same argument?

The answer is 'yes'.

Comment: Thanks Jay, i had a couple of errors while trying to make it work, because of some arguments which i forgot to define, but once checked again it worked as your concrete answer said... 

In other words, Functions arguments are passed through nested functions.